# Assign role/profile definitions to Saltstack minions during VM creation (vSphere)

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere, salt-stack

This does not seem to be a supported feature, so how can you achieve it without needing to manually set the roles/profiles after creating the VM?

Is it possible to pass any data to the VM (parameters/files) at creation?

Is there any preferred way to automatically assign roles/profiles at VM creation?

Answer (score 2):

One good way to assign roles to minions is through assigning a "roles" grain to the minions.

You can add grains automatically to a minions using Salt Cloud. If you're using a cloud map you can add a "grains" subsection under each minion and add roles. Here's an example:

```
cat /etc/salt/my_cluster.map

ubuntu_12.04_rackspace:
  server01:
    minion:
      - master: 10.0.0.1
        grains:
          roles:
            - dbserver
            - webserver
  server02:
    minion:
      - master: 10.0.0.1
        grains:
          roles:
            - webserver
```

Comment: That would be great if esxi was supported, but since it isn't, I'm looking for an alternative to that solution.